# How to pass different divides through function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get a page to load a div to play a video in a different area on the page.

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadText() {
  var topDiv=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World";
  //var bottomDiv=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML = "Goodbye World";
  }
</script>
```

Which allows me to click on a link like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick='loadText()'>Testing</a>
```

inside a set of `<p></p>` tags. And when you click on the link, it will then change out the p tags with the new content.

But what I would like to have  is this. Have different blocks of div tags with an id that I could possible pass to the loadText() function, and then have it render that divide with the video in it.

For example: `<a href="#" onclick='loadText("movie1")'>Testing</a>` and then the loadText function would then load in the `<p></p>` tags the proper divide for movie1.

Could someone give me an example on how I could modify the loadText function in the JavaScript to be able to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First, add a parameter to your function:

```
function loadText(id) {
```

Pass in the `id` on the call:

```
onclick='loadText("movie1")'
```

Use the `id` in the function:

```
document.getElementById(id)....
```

Comment: so the last line would look like this? var topDiv=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;